# Get data from same table with JOIN

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

As Prestashop 1.7 doesn't support simple product.wholesale_price variable.... Looking for some SQL request to get Wholesale_price in Back Office admin product catalog list to add additional column.

Currently I have this code, but it doesn't fetch `Wholesale_price` according to `id_product`. Maybe some one could assist where is my mistake?

```
public function hookActionAdminProductsListingFieldsModifier($params)
{
    // Manufacturer
    $params['sql_select']['product'] = [
        'table' => 'm',
        'field' => 'wholesale_price',
        'filtering' => \PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Admin\AbstractAdminQueryBuilder::FILTERING_LIKE_BOTH
        ];
    
    $params['sql_table']['m'] = [
        'table' => 'product',
        'join' => 'LEFT JOIN',
        'on' => 'p.`id_product` = m.`id_product`',
    ];
}
```

Both fields are in the same table called ps_product.

[Database table image and fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaTz3.png)

Comment: I am not familiar with this framework syntax, but i think:- 
'table' => 'm', 'table' => 'product' -> the alias names are at different place

Comment: I have added photo of database how it looks. All information exist in one table. But cannot find correct SQL request to take them.